# Mrp produce multipe variants product in one Manufacturing Orders

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9

I am a happy new user of Odoo v9 and my company is using a lot products variants (multivariants actually - clothing industry).

The new way to define product variants is ok for me however I am surprise of something: if I prepare a SO with differents variants of one single product, it creates as many Manufacturing Orders as variants I have on the Sales Order. In the real world it is actually only one MO for my supplier (BoM is the same for every variants).

Therefore if I want to launch the manufacturing I have to get inside every MO and do "Produce -> Confirm -> Next". I often have 40 variants per product so it means 40 times the same process...

The other downside is that I have very little visibility in terms of raw materials requirements as I need to check every MO to know how much I need.

I guess it is not a bug but rather a functional downside of product variants in v8.

Any clue about how to deal with this ?

Thanks a lot,